Isn't there duplicate information in struct VkSurfaceFormatKHR's format and colorspace?
I'm recently learning Vulkan, and I came across a very small problem.
There are two members in struct VkSurfaceFormatKHR, one is format and the other is color space. However, when we set its format VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_SRGB, it implies that the image to be presented is in sRGB space. Why do we still need to set its color space VK_COLORSPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR?

Strictly speaking, you aren't setting anything, you're simply selecting one of the provided formats. The ICD will provide you a set of compatible formats and color spaces.
So a given GPU might support VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_SRGB with both the sRGB transfer function (VK_COLOR_SPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR), as well as the scRGB transfer function (VK_COLOR_SPACE_EXTENDED_SRGB_NONLINEAR_EXT). Thus the GPU would provide both options to the application, and allow the application to choose which format it would prefer. But you don't get to tell the GPU to use any format or color space you want, only combinations the GPU supports.
Typically, the application would never directly set the format and colorSpace members of VkSurfaceFormatKHR. Instead it simply copies around one the formats provided by vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR.
